# list style not showing up on chrome iOS

Tags: iphone, css, google-chrome

I'm in the process of building a web site that needs to be viewable on mobile devices. When viewing it in Safari on an iPhone 4s it looks great. If I view it in Chrome on the same device none of the styles for the navigation list show up. It ends up looking like basic html links. The links in question are, Va Leadership, Nursing, and Anesthesiology staff

Bellow is a link to the live dev site, as well as the CSS.

link: http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/category/resources/

CSS:

```
#leftNav {
    max-width: 402px;
}

#leftNav ul li a {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#leftNav ul a:hover {
    color: #85b6ce;
}
#leftNav ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #0b5a42 url('images/arrow_dark.jpg') no-repeat right;
}
#leftNav ul li:nth-child(even) {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #688879 url('images/arrow_light.jpg') no-repeat right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site renders fine for me using Google Chrome for iOS Latest on my iPhone 4s (at least it looks exactly the same as it does on Safari running on the same phone).

Try clearing Chrome's cache.

If that doesn't help, connect your iphone to Fiddler2, and see what requests are being made by your site, and see if the style-sheet request is erroring out.